# PHP merge images from external URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im trying to merge a bunch of .png images stores on the Amazon s3 and files present on the local server where the site is hosted. The codes work fine with the files on the local server but not with the external files.

here is the code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $count_images; ++$i) {
    $insert = $res['images'][$i]['src'];
    if (file_exists($insert)) {
        $photo2       = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($insert));
        $foto2W       = imagesx($photo2);
        $foto2H       = imagesy($photo2);
        $photoFrame2  = imagecreatetruecolor($foto2W, $foto2H);
        $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($photoFrame2, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($photoFrame2, 0, 0, $trans_colour);
        imagecopyresampled($photoFrame2, $photo2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 260, 260, $foto2W, $foto2H);
        imagecopy($photoFrame, $photoFrame2, 130, 0, 0, 0, 260, 260);
    }
}
```

The image url's are sent as json, which is decoded and counted and layered on top of each other. I'm able to echo the url from `$insert` and it works when trying to open them as separate images.

Am I doing something wrong with the codes or is there any thing I have to do with the Amazon s3 to make it work?

Comment: allow_url_fopen is enabled on php

Comment: I `file_exists()` returning `true`?

Comment: @JeremyLindblom it returns false and I guess its due to safe mode. Looks like ill have to contact the server. All this while I was thinking its some mistake in the codes. Thanks a lot!